# The "welcome back" message is covered by the new sticky nav bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, top-bar

This alert:
[image: alert]
has a lower `z-index` than the top-bar:
[image: top-bar]

You can notice the small line under.

Comment: The question is?

Comment: It's not a question. It's a bug. The alert should't be beneath the sticky top-bar.

Comment: Can't notice due to lack of freeehand circle...

Comment: @Veve done (y).

Comment: @AurelianoFarSuau I still can't see it, where is the freehand circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote a wise thing that [Benjamin Hodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1523776), one of our developers, once said:

> z-index inflation is one of the blights of our profession

So true …

Anyway, fixed in the next build, thanks :)

Comment: I hope you guys use sensible intervals and not intervals of 1000 or 10000 like some sites I've seen... Two elements with different z-index values, one set to 5, the other set to 99999. \*cringe\*